# Can't find file even though path should be correct

Tags: php, wamp

I really can't get what is wrong here.

I'm using WAMP and here's my paths

```
wamp   
     www  
          themeister   
               include   
                    stream   
                         gameslist.php   
                    pages   
                         test.php
```

I'm in the file test.ph and trying to open gameslist.php with this

```
<?php include('/themeister/include/stream/gameslist.php'); ?>
```

It says that the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

`include()` uses the file-system, so it is looking for `/themeister/...` in the root of the file-system, where it is not located.

You could use `'/wamp/www/themeister/include/stream/gameslist.php'` or something like (more portable):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/themeister/include/stream/gameslist.php'
```